# Using rendered="" parameter causes checkbox to evaluate to null

Tags: rendered, null-pointer

Putting checkbox inside outputpanel or using rendered on itself, will display correctly, but will cause null de-reference when its used in the class.

What is the reason behind?

This works:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!receiveCopy}" title="It will send a copy" />Receive a copy of email.
```

This does not:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!renderBox}">
     <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!receiveCopy}" title="It will send a copy" />Receive a copy of email. 
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Neither this:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox rendered="{!renderBox}" value="{!receiveCopy}" title="It will send a copy" />Receive a copy of email.
```

Controller

```
public boolean receiveCopy{get;set{receiveCopy= value;}}
public PageReference selectContractor (){
        boolean receiveCopy;
        if(receiveCopy==null){
             receiveCopy = false;
        }
        selectedCase.Receive_Copy__c = receiveCopy; //   <-- Error here
```

**Edit**: Please note, that error happens irrespectively if box is checked or not. It always comes up as null.

Comment: please add your VF controller (the essence only please) - unlike SObject boolean fields, a controller Boolean will not be initialized to true or false; it will initialize to null so any reference to that controller variable before being set will cause a attempt to deref null object. A useful best practice is to make the getters for controller booleans do something like this: `return foo == null ? false : foo;`

Comment: In this case the foo will always be false.

Comment: not true; if setter has executed from a checkbox checked true, , foo will be true

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem.

The variable that is used in rendered="" parameter was set as transient.

Probably it is somehow unreachable by VF after first instantiate in pageblockTable earlier in the page.

Comment: Also be careful with two same declaration of variable name receiveCopy at class level and method level.It might confuse you in future.